# Merging Scala Spark sql schemas

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark

I'm trying to merge two dataframes and create a dataframe with a new column containing the other dataframe as an array.  Does anyone know how this can be implemented in scala?

//Schema 1

```
PRIM_KEY: decimal(20,0) (nullable = true)
|-- SOME_DECIMAL: decimal(20,0) (nullable = true)
|-- SOME_INTEGER: integer (nullable = true)
```

//Schema 2

```
PRIM_KEY: decimal(20,0) (nullable = true)
|-- COLUMN1: string (nullable = false)
|-- COLUMN2: string (nullable = false)
```

//Resulting schema

```
RIM_KEY: decimal(20,0) (nullable = true)
|-- SOME_DECIMAL: decimal(20,0) (nullable = true)
|-- SOME_INTEGER: integer (nullable = true)
|-- an_array: array (nullable = true)
|    |-- element: String (containsNull = false)
```

Comment: can you also add dataframes and expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach would be to create an `UDF` that combines two lists into one, perform a `groupBy` on the joined dataframes, and apply the `UDF` like in the following:

```
val df1 = Seq(
  (1, 100.1, 10),
  (2, 200.2, 20)
).toDF("pk", "col1", "col2")

val df2 = Seq(
  (1, "a1", "b1"),
  (1, "c1", "d1"),
  (2, "a2", "b2")
).toDF("pk", "str_col1", "str_col2")

def combineLists = udf(
  (a: Seq[String], b: Seq[String]) => a ++ b
)

val df3 = df1.join(df2, Seq("pk")).
  groupBy(df1("pk"), df1("col1"), df1("col2")).agg(
    combineLists(collect_list(df2("str_col1")), collect_list(df2("str_col2"))).alias("arr_col")
  ).
  select(df1("pk"), df1("col1"), df1("col2"), col("arr_col"))

df3.show
+---+-----+----+----------------+
| pk| col1|col2|         arr_col|
+---+-----+----+----------------+
|  1|100.1|  10|[c1, a1, d1, b1]|
|  2|200.2|  20|        [a2, b2]|
+---+-----+----+----------------+
```

Comment: Thanks Leo!  This actually does help.  This may be obvious but since I'm new to scala and spark, its not obvious to me.  but let's just say I had a single result in df1 but I wanted all the results of df2 to be added to that one row as a an array column.  How would I change the udf and the  join to handle this scenario?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you can redefine the `UDF` as `def toArrCol = udf((c0: String, c1: String, c2: String) => Array(c0, c1, c2))` with `c0` representing the selected column in `df1`.  Note that `c0` is cast as String to match with the other arguments type as Spark does not support Array[Any] schema.

Comment: So basically what I need to be able to do is to convert the results of a dataframe into a org.apache.spark.sql.Column containing an array with every row in the dataframe listed as an element in the array.

Comment: So, I guess what you're seeking is data grouping.  I've revised my answer with slightly different dataframe content to illustrate the proposed solution.

Answer (score 0):

The result you are seeking:

```
RIM_KEY: decimal(20,0) (nullable = true)
|-- SOME_DECIMAL: decimal(20,0) (nullable = true)
|-- SOME_INTEGER: integer (nullable = true)
|-- an_array: array (nullable = true)
|    |-- element: String (containsNull = false)
```

Let me tell you first:

array (nullable = true) is not a datatype but its a data structure.
So you can't at all define schema as DataType Array.

One way is to concatenate with string using concat_ws and perform a withcolumn operation on the 2nd dataset.

E.G:

```
val tmpDf = test2Df.select(concat_ws(",", col("NAME"), col("CLASS")).as("ARRAY_COLUMN"))
val mergedDf = test1Df.withColumn("ARRAY_COLUMN",tmpDf.col("ARRAY_COLUMN"))
```

I don't understand what is your use case to use an array type as schema but instead you can use the concatenated result and convert into Array.

Hope this helps you, i know am bit late here to answer but still I'll be happy if it helps you even now.